# In spring-data-elasticsearch with High Level Rest Client, when does the RestClient closed?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a question about the relationships between `High Level REST Client` and `spring-data-elasticsearch`.

In my spring-boot project, I created the `RestClientConfig` for the connection,

```java
// Config file
@Configuration
@EnableElasticsearchAuditing
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.endpoints}")
    private String endpoint;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${spring.data.elasticsearch.client.reactive.password}")
    private String pwd;

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {
        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
            .connectedTo(endpoint)
            .withBasicAuth(username, pwd)
            .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

and using `ElasticSearchRepository` to send some requests to the cluster.

```java
// repository
public interface TestRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<Test, String> {
}

// I use the repository for whole request to the elasticsearch cluster 
testRepo.save(/* object */)
```

Of course it works well, however, I'm really curious about when the client closed. (As I know, [I should close the rest-client when I finished the job.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-getting-started-initialization.html) do I have to close it by myself?(if so, when?) or the `spring-data-elasticsearch` do it for me?)

Could you please let me know how it works? Any links for codes or documents will be tremendously thankful because I couldn't find any.

Thank you!

Comment: I’m not 100% sure I’m right; but because the RestClient was created with @Bean annotation, it will removed(closed too, of course) automatically when the Spring container has been exited. This question was came from my lack of understanding in Spring. What a shame :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Data Elasticsearch never closes the client as it does not create it, you create it in your configuraiton.

And like the linked document states:

> you should close the high-level client when you are **well and truly done with it**

Spring Data Elasticsearch cannot know if and when your application does not need the connection to Elasticsearch any more.

So you might keep a reference to the client and close it if you think you really don't need it. But any calls to ElasticsearchOperations or repositories will fail after that.

Actually I never heard of a problem because of wasted resources of a single instance of this class in an application, I'd say don't bother with closing it.